# visual studio & printers zebra

Tags: visual-studio

у меня стоит задача распечатать файл PRN на принтере zebra (ip 10.168.17.66)
нашел пример в сети рабочий

```
try
 {
     // Open connection
     System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
     client.Connect("10.168.17.66", 9100);

     // Write ZPL String to connection
     System.IO.StreamWriter writer =
     new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
     writer.Write(
        "^XA" +     "^FO50,50" +     "^A0N50,50" +     "^FDHello, World!^FS" +     "^XZ"
        );
     writer.Flush();

     // Close Connection
     writer.Close();
     client.Close();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     // Catch Exception
 }
```

строку Hello, World! распечатывает. но когда вместо этих данных пытаюсь вставить содержимое моего файла prn, ругается что строка содержит неправильные символы.
Например на сроке

```
^FT820,1286^A@B,25,36,TT0003M_^FH\^CI17^F8^FD(01)  11602221011336^FS^CI0
```

РУГАЕТСЯ НА   \  слэш  и стрелка вверх (  \ ^ ), как это победить?

Comment: Не может быть проблемы в кодеровке файла?

Comment: Слеши в строках нужно дублировать (экранировать)

Comment: ругается на символ \  в строке типа string. заменил его на  (char)92 , в программе не ругается, но этикетка выходит пустая (с помощью экранирования такой же варианат \\). буду думать дальше :)))